# Understanding strong approximation

Tags: automorphic-forms

I want to understand the adelic point of view on automorphic forms. I use Gelbart's notations: $\mathbb{A}$ for the adeles, $G$ for the group $GL_2$, $K_\infty$ for $SO(2)$, $K_0^N$ for the adelic analogue of the congruence subgroup $\Gamma(N)$. By strong approximation,
$$G_{\mathbb{A}} = G_{\mathbb{Q}} G_\infty^+ K_0^N$$

and that
$$G_\mathbb{Q} \cap G_\infty^+ \prod_p K_p^N = \Gamma_0(N)$$

How does this imply
$$Z_\mathbb{A}G_{\mathbb{Q}} \backslash G_\mathbb{A} / K_0^N K_\infty \simeq \Gamma_0(N) \backslash SL_2(\mathbb{R}) / SO(2)?$$